# How to handle n sub-pages in a sitemap

Tags: website-design, web, sitemap, page

How would I go about displaying sub-pages in a sitemap if it is uncertain how many there will be? E.g. for part of a website that will be continually added to

See this example:

[image: sitemap]

I would like to make it clear that the sub-pages could be any number, as opposed to a specified amount

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general standard is to show a page stack.  Taken from [Jesse James Garrett's visual vocab for IA](https://www.ischool.utexas.edu/~i385e/readings/garrett-a_visual_vocabulary.htm):

> Use a pagestack to indicate a group of functionally identical pages whose navigational properties are immaterial to the macrostructure of the site. Similarly, a filestack represents a group of files that receive identical navigational treatment and can be classified as a single entity (such as a collection of downloadable games or a library of PDF instruction manuals).

It looks like a pile of documents or files.

See image on right hand below:

[image]